# Show string in bullting format

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have one sting " abcde | hdsjkhdsjdh | hsdkjsahdkj |dkshjkshd "

i have to show this string in this format

- abcde
- hdsjkhdsjdh
- hsdkjsahdkj
- dkshjkshd

but due to the problem text area height and width string look like this

- abcde
- hdsjkhd
- sjdh
- hsdkjsahdkj 
  dkshj
  kshd

I cant change the size of text area. Your help is respectable.

Comment: My English is not fluent.. but what is a 'bullting'? Even translate.google cann't translate it.

Comment: @beryllium The OP means "bulleted"

Comment: what text area are you talking about (the exact control name and code how you're using it will be very helpful)? is your problem that you can't only change size of control? or you can't change size of control due app requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Then you'll need to either change the font size to be smaller when you have too much text to fit in the field (you might be able to set it to adjust automatically -- such as UILabel's [adjustFontSizeToFitWidth](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth)) or you'll need to set how the end of the string gets truncated (the line break mode).

What kind of field is this?